# Object.create(null) in Javascript & creating new top-level objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

If this question is too vague, lemme know and I'll take it down or try to add more code examples, thanks!

This post is inspired by [Yehuta Katz' article on "Understanding Prototypes"](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

In Javascript you can utilize prototypes by using `Object.create()` and this will produce a dependency/inheritance much like seen in many OOP languages. If a parameter of `null` is passed to the `create()` method, then this new object will be a top-level object, the same level as `Object.prototype`.

Now, maybe this is just my years of Java and C#, but when would one ever create a top-level object? If you aren't satisfied with the fields/methods in `Object.prototype`, why not just extend it and make your own pseudo-top-level object?

**Example:**
In this example, person is a top-level object. Thus, it did not inherit the standard methods contained in `Object.prototype` such as `toString()`, `hasOwnProperty()`, `valueOf()`, etc.

```
var person = Object.create(null);

// instead of using defineProperty and specifying writable,
// configurable, and enumerable, we can just assign the
// value directly and JavaScript will take care of the rest
person['fullName'] = function() {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

// this time, let's make man's prototype person, so all
// men share the fullName function
var man = Object.create(person);
man['sex'] = "male";

var yehuda = Object.create(man);
yehuda['firstName'] = "Yehuda";
yehuda['lastName'] = "Katz";

yehuda.sex        // "male"
yehuda.fullName() // "Yehuda Katz"
```

Comment: Generally? When you want to avoid mishaps - (using objects for maps for instance) - the actual number of cases where you'd want this in real objects is very rare though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructing `{}` or `new Object` yields an object which has a prototype, as you said. Constructing with `Object.create(null)` builds an object with empty prototype and thus no inherited members.

A good use case I can think about is when you actually need an absolutely memberless object, e.g., to perform a safe iteration:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    /*
      in normal conditions, you must ensure that object hasOwnProperty(key)
      so you know you're iterating on actual members.
     */
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         console.log("key: " + key + "; value: " + obj[key]);
     }
}
```

but with this approach you ensure you don't have ANY prototype and thus every property will be own by default.

```
obj = Object.create(null);
//to-do populate your object keys here, treating it like a hash instead of an object.
for(var key in obj) {
     /*
       this operation is safe and also this object is safe to be populated
       in server-side javascript (e.g. nodejs) via a POST request.
       a common use case is to SERIALIZE this object quickly, while the
       previous IF could provide some overhead.
     */
     console.log("key: " + key + "; value: " + obj[key]);
}
```

So you can safely treat the object as a hash and iterate it as I told, holding only true data.

Another possible use case is when you want to build your own prototype from scratch (even a toString function OR NOT DEFINING CERTAIN FUNCTIONS in the Object prototype) and create a brand-new hierarchy. This could be useful only for frameworks, perhaps. It's a bit cumbersome but could be useful in the OOP approach.